# Wildcard certificate for Subdomains?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am in a situation where i have to use HTTPS.
(chrome decided to stop getUserMedia in HTTP ).

The Question is, is it possible to assign wildcard Domains?
Here are a few of my sites

1. test.nfgold.me
2. slave.nfgold.me
3. *.nfgold.me

Currently **without** using HTTPS, I have the following configuration in my nginx:

```
server {
    server_name *.nfgold.me;-
    charset utf-8;

    .....
}
```

And this works without fail.

I have used letsencrypt in a few of my projects but it does not seem to support wildcards?

I tried the following config and it does not work:

```
server {
        server_name .nfgold.me;
        rewrite ^ https://*.nfgold.me$request_uri? permanent;
    }

server {
        server_name .nfgold.me;
        rewrite ^ https://*.nfgold.me$request_uri? permanent;
    }

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name *.nfgold.me;-
    charset utf-8;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nfgold.me/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nfgold.me/privkey.pem;
    ....
    }
```

Is there an alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an alternative for this ? Any Suggestion.

While Let's Encrypt <strike>does not give you wildcard certificates</strike><sup>1</sup> you can have a certificate with multiple subdomains. From  [their FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/):

> Can I get a certificate for multiple domain names (SAN certificates or UCC certificates)?
>
> Yes, the same certificate can contain several different names using the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) mechanism.

And of course you can shop for a wildcard certificate elsewhere, i.e. many CA offer these.

---

<sup>1</sup> Starting with 01/2018 you can also get wildcard certificates from Let's Encrypt

Comment: Let's encrypt let you create wildcard certificates.

Comment: @LuigiLopez: This answer is from 2016. Let's Encrypt started to issue wildcard certificates in 01/2018. I've updated the answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for wildcard subdomains on lets encrypt, use DNS verification.

```
sudo certbot -d *.example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

After this, you have to manually add the certificates routes to your server block.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to create a detailed post explaining how to create a wildcard certificated. I hope this post can help:

```
sudo certbot certonly \
  --cert-name mydomain.com \
  --dns-digitalocean \
  --dns-digitalocean-credentials ~/.secrets/do_token.ini \
  --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory \
  -d "*.mydomain.com" \
  -d mydomain.com \
  -i nginx
```

The details can be found here:
https://huogerac.hashnode.dev/add-wildcard-https-on-digital-ocean-using-certbot-ubuntu-20-nginx-cko511nxv04in83s15uxxbeea